# maven: execute without actually building anything

Tags: java, maven, maven-exec-plugin

I have a project with finalised version in pom files , lets say 12.3.45 .
I have built the code for this version some time ago already, all the built jars are in the local maven repo.
Then at some point I have run mvn clean, so all the target folders are being removed. 
And now I want to execute some code, as quickly as possible, using mvn exec:java. Preferably without building anything, because why not? all the jars at some point were already built, and I know there were no code changes after that. How can I force maven to execute the code as fast as possible , not recompile anything, and just reuse the jars from the local repo? 
Thanks.

Comment: I do not think, this is possible without building maven project to execute a java class.Other may comment on this.

Comment: gradle.properties is located in GRADLE_USER_HOME directory or if you want you can create inside .gradle directory.

Answer (score 1):

- If your artifacts are in a local or remote repository you can use them as dependencies.
- You can use exec-maven-plugin's options includeProjectDependencies or includePluginDependencies to use them in java execution
  https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#includePluginDependencies. includeProjectDependencies option is enabled (true) by default.
- You can execute exec-maven-plugin without building anything with `mvn exec:java` command

Instructions:

To run exec-maven-plugin you would need a main class to run. I assume you have one in your project. If you don't - you need to make a separate project with a main class.

1. Create a blank maven project.
2. In the project add exec-maven-plugin configuration. Set the mainClass

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>pack.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

3. Include you artifacts as dependencies to the project

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
        <version>12.3.45</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

4. Run `mvn exec:java` to execute `com.my.package.MyMainClass` main class from `my.group.myartifact` artifact

**Edits**:

- includeProjectDependencies option is enabled (true) by default

Comment: This is not very helpful, because this property includeProjectDependencies is already TRUE by default. See documentation https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#includePluginDependencies